# Awesomplete javascript regex escaping special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using awesomplete to make search suggestions.
I've made a filter that only makes suggestions if input matches beginning of words.
But I have a hard time escaping æøå and ÆØÅ - so if I type in "åben" it will now match with "genåben" which it shouldn't.
Also if I type in "ønske" it doesn't match with "ønskeliste" which it should.

I've tried a bunch of things, and the latest I tried was this:

```
_.FILTER_WORDSTART = function(text, input) {
    return RegExp("\\b" + $.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

$.regExpEscape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\&").replace(/[^\w\sæøå-]/gi, '');
};
```

But doesn't make any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Try `RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + `...

Comment: Doesn't `.replace(/[^\w\sæøå-]/gi, '')` remove those characters from the string? You won't match them if they've been removed.

Comment: Hmm. Is it really an "escape" if the sequence is removed entirely?